# Variable length string SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data:

```
String
K40 
I84 
G401    
M232    
L72
```

And I am looking to obtain the following output

```
String
K40 
I84 
G40 
M23 
L72
```

Where those will a length of 4 are reduced by one. And those  of length 3 are retained. The code I have used thus far is:

```
(left([string], len([string]) - 1))
```

However, this alters the string irrespective of length.

Using SQL Server 2008.

Many thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `LEFT([String], 3)`? Am I missing something?

Comment: You're not missing something, for some reason it would seem I was making the task more difficult than it should have been. Thank you very much for the suggestion. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT LEFT(YOUR_COLUMN, 3) FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(YOUR_COLUMN, 1, 3) As AliasName from TableName
```